# How to invoke TestNG Custom Test Listener with in Jbehave

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, jbehave

I have crated custom TestNG TestListener and need to set Attribute with in @When block in jbehave.
I need to access attribute value with in my custom test listener class

```
@Listeners(TestReportListener.class)
public class MyJBehaveScenario {

@Given("the balance is <balance>")
public void createAccount(@Named("balance") int balance) {
    account = new Account(balance);
}

@When("the requests <request>")
public void requestMoney(@Named("request") int amount) {
  Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute("ABC", "XYZ");
}

@Then("the card should be returned")
public void cardShouldBeReturned() {
  System.out.println("Completed")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try doing something like this.

First have your listener also behave as if it were a singleton.

```
public class TestReportListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    private static TestReportListener instance;
    private String myAttribute;

    private static void setInstance(TestReportListener ins) {
        instance = ins;
    }
    public static TestReportListener getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public TestReportListener() {
        //Make sure you are using TestNG 6.10 because this version of TestNG ensures that
        //TestNG does not register duplicate listener instances into it.
        setInstance(this);
    }

    public String getMyAttribute() {
        return myAttribute;
    }

    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        this.myAttribute=testResult.getName();
        //do some work
    }

    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        //do some more work
    }
}
```

Now your modified test class could look something like below:

```
@Listeners(TestReportListener.class)
public class MyJBehaveScenario {
    @Given("the balance is <balance>")
    public void createAccount(@Named("balance") int balance) {
        account = new Account(balance);
    }

    @When("the requests <request>")
    public void requestMoney(@Named("request") int amount) {
        Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute("ABC", "XYZ");
    }

    @Then("the card should be returned")
    public void cardShouldBeReturned() {
        System.out.println("Completed");
        //Now lets try accessing the attribute from our listener
        String attribute = TestReportListener.getInstance().getMyAttribute();
        System.out.println("Value of the attribute is " : attribute)
    }
}
```

Would that work for you ?

Comment: I tried this but does not work for me.
Is there any possibility get Test result context in jbehave likes in ITestResult in TestNG

Comment: @AshanJayasundara You would need to tell us what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: I have already developed test reporting functionality by analyzing  log file,It was built by using TestNG [ to get test result, exection time, ...]
Now i need to apply same mechanism to jbehave Test reporting

Comment: Why not access the current test method's report object via Reporter.getCurrentTestResult() from within a beforeScenario (or) afterScenario [ am referring to hooks ] ? That should let you do this no ? You can also think of accessing the same from within a gherkin.formatter.Formatter#startOfScenarioLifeCycle/ gherkin.formatter.Formatter#endOfScenarioLifeCycle. Since scenarios are going to be run in the same thread, you should be able to access the current test result.